# Laravel 8 get only api route names

Tags: laravel, api, routes

I want to get only API route names. How can I get all my route names inside of my api.php ?

I'm trying the code below but it lists all the routes of my app.

```
Route::getRoutes();
```

I'm waiting for your help

Comment: Can you show some code what did you do/try so far?

Comment: Just I make a small improvement on this. There is no code to show.

Answer (score 3):

One way to determine is by checking the prefix:

```
$apiRoutes = collect();
$apiRoutesNames = [];
foreach (\Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    if ($route->action['prefix'] !== 'api') {
        continue;
    }
    $apiRoutes->push($route);
    $apiRoutesNames[] = $route->action['as'];
}

$apiRoutesNames = array_filter($apiRoutesNames);
```

This will work if you did not change the prefix in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and clean Laravel 9.

There are few ways to do that, you may get all contents of the api.php, or directly get all information from your RouteServiceProvider.php.

I changed my RouteServiceProvider.php

```
    class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/dashboard';
    public const API_PREFIX = '/api'; // I added this line
```

and changed boot method to this:

```
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix(self::API_PREFIX) // to make it dynamic
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

After that this code should give you all the api routes:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

collect(Route::getRoutes())->filter(function ($route){ 
    return $route->action['prefix'] === RouteServiceProvider::API_PREFIX;
});
```

Or you can use Str::startsWith

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

collect(Route::getRoutes())->filter(function ($route){
    return Str::startsWith($route->action['prefix'], RouteServiceProvider::API_PREFIX);
});
```

You can get all the information from the routes.